# Error al recargar sitio web desarrollado con react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router-dom

Actualmente eh desarrollado un sitio con `react js` y he usado `react-router-dom` para el tema de las rutas, cuando ejecuto el comando `npm run build` para tener el proyecto listo para produccion me encuentro con varias inconsistencias cuando intento dejar corriendo el sitio en subdirectorio usando xampp, las inconsistencias son las siguientes

1. Cuando coloco una ruta en el navegador que se diferenta a la ruta de raiz el navegador, por ejemplo `localhost:8085/pruebaDev/viewusers/` me devuelve lo siguiente:

¡Objeto no localizado!
No se ha localizado la URL solicitada en este servidor. Si usted ha introducido la URL manualmente, por favor revise su ortografía e inténtelo de nuevo.

2. Cuando coloco sola ruta inicial del subdirectorio carga sin ningun problema, ejemplo `localhost:8085/pruebaDev/`

Las configuraciones que eh realizado son las siguientes

1. cree el siguiente .htaccess y lo ubique en el directorio raiz de xampp,en htdocs

**Configuracion del .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pruebaDev/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

2. Archivo package.json

   ````
     "homepage": ".",
     "name": "pruebaDev",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
       "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
       "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
       "moment": "^2.29.1",
       "react": "^16.14.0",
       "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
       "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
       "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
       "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
       "redux": "^4.0.5",
       "sweetalert2": "^10.9.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app"
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
       ]
     }
   }```
   ````
3. Archivo de configuracion de las rutas App.js

`<Router basename={'/pruebaDev/'}></Router>`